# Total Commander slow search and options dialog opening

Tags: windows-10, total-commander

In my Total Commander, the Search Dialog (Alt - F7) and Options dialog (Search/Options) take cca 1 second to open. On a different user account, the Search Dialog is faster (but doesn't show up right away either). The Options Dialog is slow as well.

Why does it take so long? Any remedy for this?

I found [this thread](https://ghisler.ch/board/viewtopic.php?t=17456), but there's no resolution. I don't have any plugins installed.

PS: Total Commander is version 9.22a under Windows 10, 64bit, on very fast computer with SSD disk, 4 cores, i7-3770S 3901Mhz, 8GB Ram)

On my good old Dell Latitude D530 (much slower computer with Win XP), Total Commander 8.50 opens Search Dialog immediatelly . Options dialog takes a while but not so long as in the newer version.

Comment: I have Total Commander here (V9.22a). When I search on a top level folder, results are near instant. Are you trying to search your whole drive?  That will be slow. Can you control your search to an appropriate top level folder?

Comment: @John I am talking about *opening* the search dialog, not searching!

Comment: I click on TC Search and it opens instantly. Maybe uninstall / reinstall Total Commander and use TC 64-bit when using it

Comment: I have the exact same problem and the issue is related to windows 10 UI integration as the TC is using very ancient windows API.